# Reading from excel using oledbcommand

Tags: c#, excel

In the below code instead of specifying the tab name.. Is there anyway we can just say "select * from [tab1]"? what ever the tab name might be..

```
 OleDbCommand excelOledbCommand =
                            new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Sheet1$]", excelOledbCon);
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you wish to try?

Comment: read data from excel using c#

Comment: Yes yes, but what is the issue with the sheet name?

Comment: giving special instructions to the person who uploads the excel sheet 'first tab should be only named sheet1, otherwise my code will not read it'.. doesn't sound so great..

Comment: Can you use the Excel Com Interop?

Comment: No, can't change lot of code. wondering if there is a any simple trick..

Comment: You can select from a named range.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might help

[Tips for reading Excel spreadsheets using ADO.NET](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196)

[OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable(VS.71).aspx)

Something like

```
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\BAR.XLS;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""");
dbConnection.Open ();
try
{
    // Get the name of the first worksheet:
    DataTable dbSchema = dbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable (OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    if (dbSchema == null || dbSchema.Rows.Count < 1)
    {
        throw new Exception ("Error: Could not determine the name of the first worksheet.");
    }
    string firstSheetName = dbSchema.Rows [0] ["TABLE_NAME"].ToString ();

    // Now we have the table name; proceed as before:
    OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand ("SELECT * FROM [" + firstSheetName + "]", dbConnection);
    OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader ();

    // And so on...
}
finally
{
    dbConnection.Close ();
}
```

Comment: @Adriaan Stander  can we read it without sheet names like sheet index ??

Answer (score 2):

```
public DataSet GetDataSetFromFile()
{
    string strFileName = _FilePath;
    string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";
    strConn += "Data Source= " + strFileName + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'";
    OleDbConnection ObjConn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
    ObjConn.Open();
    string strSheetName = getSheetName(ObjConn);
    OleDbCommand ObjCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + strSheetName + "]", ObjConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter objDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    objDA.SelectCommand = ObjCmd;
    DataSet ObjDataSet = new DataSet();
    objDA.Fill(ObjDataSet);
    ObjConn.Close();
    return ObjDataSet;
}

private string getSheetName(OleDbConnection ObjConn)
{
    string strSheetName = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dtSheetNames = ObjConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (dtSheetNames.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            strSheetName = dtSheetNames.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        }
        return strSheetName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to get the sheet name", ex);
    }
}
```