# "Syntax error in FROM clause" Excel in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office365, oledb

i have an Excel file i want to raed it in c# using the ***OleDb*** like the following code:

```
    string sheetName = "sheet1";
    try
    {
        string stringConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=excelfile.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=0';";
    
        OleDbConnection OleDbConnection_ = new OleDbConnection(stringConnection);
        OleDbCommand OleDbCommand_ = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetName + "$]; ", OleDbConnection_);
        OleDbConnection_.Open();
    
        DataTable DataTable_ = new DataTable();
        DataTable_.Load(OleDbCommand_.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
    
        OleDbConnection_.Close();
    
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Everything is working fine, just when i change the **SheetName** Value to ***" topos .architectures. bureaux "*** like the name in the xls file that i have, an exception was shown:

***Syntax error in FROM clause.***

what i messed it up here, thank you.

Comment: Double check the name of the sheet. You've added a space between `topos` and `.architectures`

Comment: thank you for your answer.The name of the sheet i get it programmatically using a function that get me the name of the first sheet in an excel file, that's mean the space is there

Comment: Can you put a break point on `OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetName + "$];` and compare the name to the excel sheet?

Comment: Yes i did an i found it's the same, the renaming of the sheet in file make it works, but i need to use the name in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the dots in the Sheet name, the dots should be an #.

Like that:

`"select * from ['" + sheetName.Replace('.', '#') + "$'];"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove the `$` in `"select * from [" + sheetName + "$]; "`

The `$` is indeed use in references in Excel itself, but I think is does not apply to the OleDB command syntax

See this question for reference: [Reading from excel using oledbcommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429713/reading-from-excel-using-oledbcommand)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that's really help me, but is not the answer to my problem.